# .Net Core View Components won't work without custom View Model

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a MVC.Net Core 2.0 application (it was originally 1.1 before I upgraded it) that has an odd quirk to it. In order to call a View Component from my page, I have to create a custom View Model. If I use a built in type, like string, the routing handler fails to find it.

Example:
I created a pretty simple ViewComponent that I am trying to call from my View, that only need a single string. But if I created with InvokeAsync(string) instead of InvokeAsync(customVm) I get an error suggesting the routing is trying to use the string parameter as part of the path.

ViewComponent:

```
public class SkilledQaPreviousComments : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string vm)
    {
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

Calling View:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync(nameof(SkilledQaPreviousComments), new { vm = Model.QaReviewEditReasonPrevious })
```

Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(name: "areaRoute", template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

File locations:

[image]

Error Message given Model.QaReviewEditReasonPrevious = "[\"single\"]":

The view 'Components/SkilledQaPreviousComments/["test"]' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Areas/NurseForms/Views/Signature/Components/SkilledQaPreviousComments/["test"].cshtml
/Areas/NurseForms/Views/Shared/Components/SkilledQaPreviousComments/["test"].cshtml
/Views/Shared/Components/SkilledQaPreviousComments/["test"].cshtml

If I change the view component to accept an int and pass 1 I get the same error just with '1' instead of '["test"]'.

I just can't figure out why it's not looking for Default.cshtml. Other view components in the project are working, but everyone of them has a custom view model. I'd rather not create a custom view model just to hold a string every time but right now that's my only option.

Ideas/Obvious things I've done wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this issue, it is caused by the missmatch `View` method you want to return.

Check the [ViewComponent](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a67d9363e22be8ef63a1a62539991e1da3a6e30e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewComponent.cs) source code, it defines below methods to return `View`:

```
public ViewViewComponentResult View<TModel>(string viewName, TModel model);
public ViewViewComponentResult View<TModel>(TModel model);
public ViewViewComponentResult View(string viewName);
public ViewViewComponentResult View();
```

When you return `return View(vm);` which vm is a string, it will match to `View(string viewName);` for best match, and it will look for the specific viewName instead of return the Default view and model.

You could try code below to use `View<TModel>(TModel model);`.

```
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string vm)
    {
        return View<string>(vm);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Tao, that was the issue!